# This is a c# coding with sql. Syntax error when value changes

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, datagridview

I am newbie in c# and sql. My code is showing syntax error when I'm inserting contact no. having 10 digits but no error when it is less than it. data type in table is also `big int.` I am using sql server 2008. Please help.
The code is given below.

```
            sQuery = "insert into ReceiveChallanPrint1 (ChallanNO,ReferencNo,Title,Author,ISBN,ChallanDate," +
                "ReceivedOn,Publisher,PublisherAddress,PublisherContactNo,PublisherEmail,TemplateName," +
                "TemplateSubject,TemplateBody,EmailAttachment1"
                + ")";

        sQuery = sQuery + " values(";

        sQuery = sQuery + "'" + Convert.ToInt32( dgvChallanActive.Rows[i].Cells["ChallanNo"].Value.ToString()) + "',";
        sQuery = sQuery + "'"+Convert.ToInt32( dgvChallanActive.Rows[i].Cells["ReferenceNo"].Value.ToString())+ "',";
        sQuery = sQuery + "'" + Convert.ToString(dgvChallanActive.Rows[i].Cells["Title"].Value) + "',";
        sQuery = sQuery + "'" + Convert.ToString(dgvChallanActive.Rows[i].Cells["Author1"].Value) + "',";
        sQuery = sQuery + "'" + dgvChallanActive.Rows[i].Cells["ISBN"].Value + "',";


        sQuery = sQuery + "'" + Convert.ToString(dgvChallanActive.Rows[i].Cells["ChallanDate"].Value) + "',";
        sQuery = sQuery + "'" + dtpReceivedDate.Value.ToShortDateString() + "',";

        sQuery = sQuery + "'" + Convert.ToString(dgvChallanActive.Rows[i].Cells["Publisher"].Value) + "',";
        sQuery = sQuery + "'" + Convert.ToString(dgvChallanActive.Rows[i].Cells["PublisherAddress"].Value) + "',";


       // sQuery = sQuery + "'" + Convert.ToInt32(dgvChallanActive.Rows[i].Cells["PublisherContactNo"].Value.ToString()) + "',";

        sQuery = sQuery + "'" + Convert.ToInt32(dgvChallanActive.Rows[i].Cells["PublisherContactNo"].Value.ToString()) + "',";

        sQuery = sQuery + "'" + Convert.ToString(dgvChallanActive.Rows[i].Cells["PublisherEmail"].Value) + "',";
        sQuery = sQuery + "'" + Convert.ToString(cboEmailTemplate.Text) + "',";
        sQuery = sQuery + "'" + sSubject + "',";
        sQuery = sQuery + "'" +sBody+ "',";
        sQuery = sQuery + "'" + lblAttachment.Text.Trim() + "'";
        sQuery = sQuery + ")";


        DBInteraction.DBOperation.sConnectionString = GlobalFuncs.sConnectionString;
        sRetVal = DBOperation.ExecuteDBOperation(sQuery, DBOperation.OperationType.INSERT, null, ref dt);

         if (sRetVal != GlobalFuncs.SUCCESS)
        { MessageBox.Show("no insert "); }

        return sRetVal;
}

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
```

As i use debugging option in this code so after crossing PublisherContactNo. It comes out from try box.I am taking data from gridview.

Comment: Please don't build up sql using strings, use parameterised SQL, see the following http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/.

Comment: Try changing `Convert.ToInt32(dgvChallanActive.Rows[i].Cells["PublisherContactNo"].Value.ToString())` to `Convert.ToInt64(dgvChallanActive.Rows[i].Cells["PublisherContactNo"].Value.ToString())`

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then, please accept it.  Please also change your code to use parameterized SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Convert.ToInt32(dgvChallanActive.Rows[i].Cells["PublisherContactNo"].Value.ToSt‌​ring())` to `Convert.ToInt64(dgvChallanActive.Rows[i].Cells["PublisherContactNo"].Value.ToSt‌​ring())`

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine if you change

```
Convert.ToInt32(dgvChallanActive.Rows[i].Cells["PublisherContactNo"].Value.ToString())
```

to

```
Convert.ToInt64(dgvChallanActive.Rows[i].Cells["PublisherContactNo"].Value.ToString())
```

But this is not at all a good practice of writing code. You need to use parameterised queries, e.g.:

```
string query = "insert into tbl1(col1,col2,col3) values(@col1,@col2,@col3)";
```

and then you need to pass values for parameters.